# dictionary only displaying last printed value (loop problems)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys so i'm a few months into python and i'm trying a function that stores the input into a dictionary and print it out.  MY problem is I can only get the function to print out the last result. Please help if you can.

I can only get it to break so far but not print out my input.

```
def results():
  name = 0
  score = 0
  grades = {}

  while score != 'q':

name = input('Enter the name of the student:')

    score = input('Enter the score of the student:')

    grades[name] = score
    if name == 'q':
      continue
    if score == 'q':
      break

  return grades
  print('Okay, printing results now!')
  print(grades.items())

results()
```

expect to see the results of the dictionary printed out.

(Full disclosure i'm a little embarrassed asking pros like you guys for help on my dumb little problem lol so please be gentle and if you have any tips on learning better etc i'll gladly take them.)

Comment: For k,v in dict.items() is what you want. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)

Comment: Also your return statement is before the print so that will never print because return ends the function. You’d need to set something equal the function then print that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check this out

```
def results():    
    grades = {}

    while True:
        name = input('Enter the name of the student: ')

        # Break the program if the user enters the 'q' key for the name
        if name == 'q':
            break

        score = input('Enter the score of the student: ')
        grades[name] = score 

    print('Okay, printing results now!')
    print(grades)

results()
```

On running:

```
Enter the name of the student: John Doe
Enter the score of the student: 89
Enter the name of the student: Daniel Rose
Enter the score of the student: 77
Enter the name of the student: Kivy Havillah
Enter the score of the student: 58
Enter the name of the student: q
Okay, printing results now!
{'John Doe': '89', 'Daniel Rose': '77', 'Kivy Havillah': '58'}
```

**Note:**
You don't need to initialize the variables name and score to 0 at first since they aren't used for counting the number of loops.

Comment: You should add a return statement and return the grades dictionary from the function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code seems to be working fine, just a few minor changes:

```
def results():
    name, score, grades = 0, 0, {}

    while True:
        name = input('Enter the name of the student:')
        score = input('Enter the score of the student:')

        grades[name] = score
        if name == '' or score == '':
            break

    print('Okay, printing results now!')
    print(grades)
    return grades

results()
```